# Could not open '/dev/pve/vm-130-disk-0': No such file or directory because of "Unable to resume pve-data-tpool"

Tags: server, hard-drive, virtualization, raid, lvm

We are facing an issue while starting the VM on the proxmox with the below error

kvm: -drive file=/dev/pve/vm-130-disk-0,if=none,id=drive-virtio0,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native,detect-zeroes=on: Could not open '/dev/pve/vm-130-disk-0': No such file or directory

We tried to understand the issue and went through a couple of threads to understand it but did not succeed with it.

Here is a little information about the system

lvs:

```
LV              VG  Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
base-129-disk-0 pve Vri---tz-k  600.00g data                                               
data            pve twi---tz--   18.03t                                                   
data_meta0      pve -wi-------   16.00g                                                   
root            pve -wi-ao----   96.00g                                                   
swap            pve -wi-ao----   20.00g                                                   
vm-100-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  100.00g data                                               
vm-103-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  250.00g data                                               
vm-105-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  610.00g data                                               
vm-106-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  500.00g data                                               
vm-110-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  800.00g data                                               
vm-116-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  600.00g data                                               
vm-118-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  650.00g data                                               
vm-120-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--    1.17t data                                               
vm-127-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  150.00g data                                               
vm-130-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  250.00g data                                               
vm-131-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  150.00g data                                               
vm-137-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--   50.00g data                                               
vm-138-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  100.00g data                                               
vm-141-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  800.00g data                                               
vm-144-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  100.00g data                                               
vm-148-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz-- 1000.00g data                                               
vm-152-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  500.00g data                                               
vm-156-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  600.00g data                                               
vm-210-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--    1.29t data                                               
vm-215-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  250.00g data                                               
vm-220-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  574.00g data                                               
vm-222-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  250.00g data                                               
vm-227-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  625.00g data                                               
vm-227-disk-1   pve Vwi---tz--  100.00g data                                               
vm-229-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  625.00g data                                               
vm-229-disk-1   pve Vwi---tz--  100.00g data                                               
vm-264-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  500.00g data
```

vgs:

```
VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
pve   2  32   0 wz--n- 18.24t 65.96g
```

lsblk:

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0 18.2T  0 disk
|-sda1               8:1    0 1007K  0 part
|-sda2               8:2    0  512M  0 part
`-sda3               8:3    0 18.2T  0 part
  |-pve-swap       253:0    0   20G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  |-pve-root       253:1    0   96G  0 lvm  /
  |-pve-data_tmeta 253:2    0 15.8G  0 lvm 
  `-pve-data_tdata 253:8    0   18T  0 lvm 
sdb                  8:16   0  4.6T  0 disk
`-sdb1               8:17   0   50G  0 part
sr0                 11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

The content of the /etc/pve/storage.conf

```
dir: local
    path /var/lib/vz
    content vztmpl,backup,iso

lvmthin: local-lvm
    vgname pve
    thinpool data
    content rootdir,images
```

lvscan:

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/swap' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/root' [96.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/data' [18.03 TiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-120-disk-0' [1.17 TiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-105-disk-0' [610.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-116-disk-0' [600.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-130-disk-0' [250.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0' [250.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-127-disk-0' [150.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/base-129-disk-0' [600.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-131-disk-0' [150.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-137-disk-0' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-141-disk-0' [800.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-144-disk-0' [100.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-156-disk-0' [600.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-118-disk-0' [650.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-210-disk-0' [1.29 TiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-138-disk-0' [100.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-215-disk-0' [250.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-220-disk-0' [574.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-106-disk-0' [500.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-152-disk-0' [500.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-222-disk-0' [250.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-227-disk-0' [625.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-227-disk-1' [100.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-229-disk-0' [625.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-229-disk-1' [100.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-148-disk-0' [1000.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-110-disk-0' [800.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-100-disk-0' [100.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-264-disk-0' [500.00 GiB] inherit
```

Since the /dev/pve/data is not active we are trying to activate using lvchange -ay /dev/pve

```
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
```

When I try to run the same command with verbose logs lvchange -ay -v /dev/pve/data

```
Activating logical volume pve/data exclusively.
    activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for pve/data.
    Loading pve-data_tmeta table (253:2)
    Suppressed pve-data_tmeta (253:2) identical table reload.
    Loading pve-data_tdata table (253:8)
    Suppressed pve-data_tdata (253:8) identical table reload.
    Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/pve-data_tmeta
    Creating pve-data-tpool
    Loading pve-data-tpool table (253:3)
    Resuming pve-data-tpool (253:3)
  device-mapper: resume ioctl on (253:3) failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume pve-data-tpool (253:3)
    Removing pve-data-tpool (253:3)
```

We are trying to bring back this missing pve-data-tpool, which is causing the issue Unable to resume pve-data-tpool. Are we missing something? Because of this issue, we are not able to start any of the vm in the proxmox server. Unfortunately, we don't have the latest backup of the VMs.

Please suggest any solution for this issue.